# Cannot add List<SomeClass<Child of bounding type for SomeClass>> to a List<SomeClass<?>>

Tags: java, list, generics

I've recently started learning Java and having a problem with the use of generics. I use a parametric and parameter upper bounded `NumberBox<T extends Number>` class that simply stores `Number` objects and compares them. Whenever I attempt to create a list of unknowns `List<NumberBox<?>>` to store any `NumberBox<T extends Number>` objects I cannot add a `List<NumberBox<Short>>` to this list of unknowns using a non-parametric method `static addList(List<NumberBox<?>> destinationList, List<NumberBox<?>> sourceList)`. However, I can add this parametric list to the list of unknowns using a parametric method `<T extends Number> static addListInference(List<NumberBox<?>> destinationList, List<NumberBox<T>> sourceList)`. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

interface Box<T> {
    public T get();
    public void set(T t);
    public int compareTo(Box<T> other);
}

class NumberBox<T extends Number> implements Box<T> {
    T t;
    public NumberBox(T t) { 
        set(t); 
    }   
    @Override
    public T get() { 
        return t; 
    }
    @Override
    public void set(T t) { 
        this.t = t; 
    }   
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Box<T> other) {
        int result = 0;
            if (t.doubleValue() < other.get().doubleValue()) {
                result = -1;
            } else if (t.doubleValue() > other.get().doubleValue()) {
                result = 1;
            } else if (t.doubleValue() == other.get().doubleValue()) {
                result = 0;
            }
        return result;      
    }
}


class MainClass {

    public static <T extends Number> 
    void addListInference(List<NumberBox<?>> destinationList, List<NumberBox<T>> sourceList) { 
        destinationList.addAll(sourceList); 
    }

    public static void addList(List<NumberBox<?>> destinationList, 
    List<NumberBox<?>> sourceList) { 
        destinationList.addAll(sourceList);     
    }   

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        // your code goes here
        List<NumberBox<?>> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<NumberBox<Short>> shortList = new ArrayList<>();
        shortList.add(new NumberBox<Short>((short) 1));
        // this one fails
        MainClass.addList(list, shortList);
        // this one works
        MainClass.addListInference(list, shortList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside: your `compareTo` method would be more simply implemented as `return Double.compare(t.doubleValue(), other.get().doubleValue());`.

Comment: Yeah I didn't know Double.compare(double, double) existed sorry for the redundant clutter.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that

```
List<NumberBox<?>>
```

is not a superclass of

```
List<NumberBox<Short>>
```

because `List<Superclass>` a superclass of `List<Subclass>`.

You can make it work without the type variable `T` using:

```
List<? extends NumberBox<?>>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information made the change now it works.